# Showing Interstitial Ad After a Specific Number of Clicks

Tags: android, admob

I want to show admob interstitial ad when a user clicks a button. But I don't want to show the ad every time the user clicks the button. I want to show it after every 3-5 times user clicks that button.

Comment: Use a `SharedPreference` to store the number of clicks every time the user clicks it. Once you get to the place where `number_of_clicks == 5` you show the AdMob Interstitial Activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
final int clickNumber = 0;
Button mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(clickNumber<=5){
                   clickNumber++;
                 }else{
                      clickNumber=0;
                      // show add here
                 }
            }
         });
```